# GET http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js not found error

Tags: node.js, express

[image][image]Below here I uploaded my index.html, package.json, server.js, app.js and MainController.js. After running node server, I am only getting index.html. But index.html requires angular.js, app.js, MainController.js. In my console im getting "GET  http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js" not found error.

Can anyone please help me out with this issue.

```
    

    
        //package.json

    
        {
          "name": "ng-include",
          "version": "1.0.0",
          "description": "",
          "main": "server.js",
          "dependencies": {
            "body-parser": "^1.17.1",
            "consolidate": "^0.14.5",
            "express": "^4.15.2",
            "html": "^1.0.0",
            "swig": "^1.4.2"
          },
          "scripts": {
            "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
          },
          "author": "mehadi",
          "license": "UNLICENSED",
          "repository": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "(https://github.com/mehadi07/JavaScript_Projects/AngularJS/ng-include)"
          },
          "devDependencies": {}
        }
    
    
        // server.js
    
        var express = require('express');
        var path = require('path');
        var bodyParser  = require('body-parser');
        var cons = require('consolidate');
    
        var app = express();
    
        app.engine('html', cons.swig);
    
        app.set('view engine', 'html');
    
        app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    
        app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'lib/')));
    
    
        app.use(bodyParser.json());
        app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
          extended: true
        }));
    
    
        app.get('/',function(req,res){
            res.render('index');
        });
    
        // Binding express app to port 3000
        app.listen(3000,function(){
            console.log('Node server running @ http://localhost:3000')
        });

//app.js

'use strict';

// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
var app = angular.module('loginApp', []);


    enter code here
    
        // MainController.js
    
        app.controller('MainController', function MainController($scope) {
    
            var employees = [
                {
                    name: "Ben",
                    gender: "Male",
                    salary: 55000,
                    city: "London"
                },
                {
                    name: "Sara",
                    gender: "Female",
                    salary: 68000,
                    city: "Chennai"
                },
                {
                    name: "Mark",
                    gender: "Male",
                    salary: 57000,
                    city: "London"
                },
                {
                    name: "Pam",
                    gender: "Female",
                    salary: 53000,
                    city: "Chennai"
                },
                {
                    name: "Todd",
                    gender: "Male",
                    salary: 60000,
                    city: "London"
                },
                    ];
    
            $scope.employees = employees;
            $scope.employeeView= "employeeTable.html";
            $scope.employeeList="employeeList.html";
        });
    
    
    
    
        //index.html
    
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en" ng-app="loginApp" class="no-js">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <title>AngularJS App</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
        </head>
    
        <body ng-controller="MainController">
            <div ng-include="'employeeTable.html'"></div>
    
            <br/> Select View:
            <select ng-model="employeeView">
                <option value="employeeTable.html"> Table </option>
                <option value="employeeList.html"> List </option>
    
            </select>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <div ng-include="employeeView"></div>
            <!--Created a scope on controller and shortend the .html format to a normal name
                -->
    
    
    
            <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
            <script src="lib/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
            <script src="app.js"></script>
            <script src="MainController.js"></script>
    
        </body>
    
        </html>
```

Comment: could you show us the directory tree

?

Comment: I did. Please check. Thank you

Comment: your directory is wrong，it seems that the root is server.js.So you can add **views ** above the js

Comment: for example: <script src="views/app.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

updated server.js file and its solved now

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/'));

// remove dir name to server anyfile
//app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/views/lib')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname)));
```